# AF_UNIX socket: select() firing when there is nothing to read

Tags: c, sockets, select

The program creates n threads for simulating n nodes in a distributed system, each has one socket it listens to and each thread can communicate to n-1 other threads through connect calls.

1. Each thread makes a call to select() to see if anything's available and if so accepts and saves the data.
2. I use ioctl with the flag FIONREAD to check the number of bytes available to be read and do an appropriate read call. Afterwards the new fd (from accept()) is closed.
3. The listening sockets are blocking. O_NONBLOCK is NOT set.
4. All n threads run the same function. All variables declared within the function use thread local storage.
5. There's no explicit synchronization done on my part. More than one thread can try to connect to the same socket at once.

Now, the problem is, once in a while, the select() in a thread on the receiving side notes something new but the amount of bytes available is 0 which it shouldn't be. This happens inconsistently.

Would be great if someone can point where I should look into. Thanks!

creating the sock

```
  if ( (nptr->sock = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) {
                perror("socket");
                exit(1);
            }
            fd_max = nptr->sock > fd_max ? nptr->sock : fd_max;

            int ok=1;
            setsockopt(nptr->sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &ok, sizeof(int));

            nptr->addr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
            snprintf(nptr->addr.sun_path, 20, "%d", nptr->id);
            //strncpy(nptr->addr.sun_path, sock_path, 20);

            if ( bind(nptr->sock, (struct sockaddr*)&(nptr->addr), sizeof(struct sockaddr_un)) < 0 ) {
                perror("bind");
                exit(1);
            }
            /* socket,  max connections */
            if ( listen(nptr->sock, 2*tot_node) < 0 ) {
                perror("listen");
                exit(1);
            }
```

sending stuff

```
for (t=0; t<tot_node; t++) {
            ...

            if ((fd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
                perror("socket");
                exit(1);
            }

            printf("Node %d: trying to req node %d... ", self->id, node_catalog[t]->id);
            if ( connect(fd, (struct sockaddr*)&(node_catalog[t]->addr), sizeof(struct sockaddr_un)) == -1 ) {
                perror("connect");
                exit(1);
            }

            buf[0] = TYPE_REQ;
            buf[1] = self->id;
            buf[2] = ts;
            buf[3] = rsc;

            write (fd, buf, 4*sizeof(int));

            //close(fd);

            printf("Node %d: sent req for resource %d to %d\n", self->id, rsc, node_catalog[t]->id);
        }
        usleep(TS_UPDATE_ITV);
```

receiving stuff

```
    FD_ZERO(&readset);
            FD_SET(self->sock, &readset);
            t = pselect(self->sock+1, &readset, NULL, NULL, &tout, NULL);
            if (t > 0 && FD_ISSET(self->sock, &readset)) {

                com_fd = accept(self->sock, NULL, NULL);

                ioctl(com_fd, FIONREAD, &t);
    #ifdef DEBUG
                printf("   Node %d: received %d bytes of data\n", self->id, t);
    #endif

                read(com_fd, buf, t);
                close(com_fd);

                dptr = (int *)buf;
                rsc = t / (sizeof(int)); /* var reuse. this is the count of ints to read */

                for (t=0; t<rsc; ) {
                    static __thread int nid, nts, nrsc;
    #ifdef DEBUG
                    printf("   Node %d: data rcvd: %d %d %d %d", self->id, *dptr, *(dptr+1), *(dptr+2), *(dptr+3));
    #endif

                   if (*dptr == TYPE_REQ) {
... } else {...}
```

Comment: There is absolutely no rule that prohibits this from happening, even if all of your code is correct. The only way to guarantee that a socket will not block is to set it non-blocking. Otherwise, you are doing the equivalent of checking that there is free space on a disk and then appending to a file -- that there *was* free space does not guarantee that there *will* *be* free space when you append. That the socket *was* readable does not guarantee that it *will* *be* readable later.

Answer (score 3):

Your code doesn't make sense. The reason that `select()` fired was that there was something to *accept*. Checking FIONREAD on a socket you've just accepted may or may not result in data being available. It depends entirely on whether the client has sent any. Not on the contract of `select()`.

If you need to know whether there is something to read, you should add the accepted socket to the read-FD set, and process it in a loop: if the listening socket is readable, call `accept()` on it, otherwise it is an accepted socket and you should call `read()` on it.

Checking FIONREAD is really just a waste of time in most circumstances.

Comment: Okay, I get what I did wrong.
Though the threads are supposed to send data immediately after connecting, the ioctl() may have had executed before anything actually became available. I changed that read call with the classic while loop.
Thank you!